# Getting 'global name not defined' error in Python using scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I've been learning scrapy from a book called Web Scraping with Python by Ryan Mitchell. There's a code in the book that gets external links from a website. Even though I'm using the same code as it is in the book (the only thing I did to it was changing 'urllib.request' to 'urllib2'), I keep getting the same error. Python version is 2.7.12.
This is the error:

```
File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
getAllExternalLinks("http://www.oreilly.com")
File "test.py", line 16, in getAllExternalLinks
internalLinks = getInternalLinks(bsObj, splitAddress(siteUrl)[0])
NameError: global name 'getInternalLinks' is not defined
```

This is the code I'm using.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urlparse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
allExtLinks = set()

allIntLinks = set()

def getAllExternalLinks(siteUrl):

    html = urlopen(siteUrl)

    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

    internalLinks = getInternalLinks(bsObj,splitAddress(siteUrl)[0])

    externalLinks = getExternalLinks(bsObj,splitAddress(siteUrl)[0])

    for link in externalLinks:

        if link not in allExtLinks:

            allExtLinks.add(link)

            print(link)

    for link in internalLinks:

        if link not in allIntLinks:

            print("About to get link: "+link)

            allIntLinks.add(link)

            getAllExternalLinks(link)

getAllExternalLinks("http://www.oreilly.com")
```

Comment: I don't know what edition of the book you are using, or where you managed to copy this snippet - but it is missing half the code. The complete example is [available on github](https://github.com/REMitchell/python-scraping/blob/master/chapter3/5-getAllExternalLinks.py).

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the example code, before compile it.
Look, there is no `getInternalLinks()` function in your code.